# Getting a form component to work with ajax in vuejs

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vuejs component which is a form. It has one field "email". The default value of "email" if given to the component from the parent as a prop named "email". When a user submits the form, I need to fire an event so that the parent can get the updated value of the "email".

So this looks like

```
<parent>
  <child :email="email" />
</parent>
```

Now the issue is my child's object looks like:

```
{
  props: ['email'],
  data() {return {d_email: this.email}
}
```

The problem is, I am always seeing a null value in the form field. This seems to be happening since my input form tag looks like this:

```
<input type="text" v-model="d_email" :value="email" />
```

If I don't use the value="email", then the child component won't update when the value of email changes in parent, which is needed.

However, since I also need to send back input changes to the parent when the form is submitted, I need to store the input value somewhere. I am using d_email for that.

However, when the child is rendered for the first time, prop email is null, and hence d_email gets initialized to null. This means that due to v-model, the inout field always shows null.

What's the recommended approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In child, watch the `email` property.

```
{
  props: ['email'],
  data() {return {d_email: this.email},
  watch:{ email(newEmail){ this.d_email = email }}
}
```

Using the watched value, your local email variable will be updated whenever the parent changes.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the docs are down on `Watch` when a computed property will work: "When you have some data that needs to change based on some other data, it is tempting to overuse watch - especially if you are coming from an AngularJS background. However, it is often a better idea to use a computed property rather than an imperative watch callback"

Comment: @MarkM Typically I might agree. In this case, however, he has a local `d_email` which is the source of `v-model` so he would minimally need a get/set computed where `get` is what you suggested in your answer, and `set` is an $emit. However, he describes updating the parent when the `form` submits, meaning (to me) he doesn't necessarily want to emit the value *immediately*. That being the case, I suggest a watch over a computed.

Answer (score 0):

To fire an event that the parent will pick up you need to add the link to the child component like:

`<child :email="email" v-on:updateemail="setemail"></child>`

Where `updateemail` is the name of the event and `setemail` is a method on the parent that gets called when the event is fired.

In the child you should make `d_email` a computed property like this:

```
computed: {
   d_email: function(){ return this.email }
 }
```

With that it should update when the parent updates the prop.

Putting it all together will give you something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src=" https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <parent></parent>
    </div>


    <script>
        Vue.component('parent', {
            template: '<child :email="email" v-on:updateemail="setemail"></child>',
            data: function(){
                return {
                    email: "initial@example.org"
                }
            },
            methods: {
                setemail: function(e){
                    console.log("email changed to: ", e)
                    this.email = e
                }
            }
        });

        Vue.component('child', {
            template: '<input id="emailinput" type="text" v-model="d_email" v-on:input="updateemail">',
            props: ['email'],
            methods: {
                updateemail: function(e) {
                    this.$emit("updateemail", e.target.value)
                }
            },
            computed: {
                d_email: function(){ return this.email }
            }

        });
        new Vue({
            el:'#app',
        });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Watch the console and you will see the parents email property getting updated as the user types. If this is hitting a server, you'll probably want the event to fire when the user submits rather than types, but that's a trivial change.

Comment: If you're going to go down this route, use a `set` value in your computed and avoid the `@input` and `updateemail` altogether.  `d_email: {get(){return this.email}, set(v){ this.$emit('updateemail', v)}}`.

Comment: That's nice @bert-evans.